# TYPO3 Extension Settings to Page Settings

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I search for a Solution, how can i give the Ext/Plugin settings to the page settings?

My first Test dont works:

```
page.10.settings =< plugin.tx_tester.settings
```

Comment: What should `page.10.settings`do?

Comment: Hi @HeinzSchilling i need the EXT: Settings for the Page Settings.

Comment: make sure your  custom extension typoscript  must be loaded before your PAGE object

Comment: I have just tried news extension setting like(settings.news <plugin.tx_news.settings) in my demo and its working fine for me https://prnt.sc/n6wol2
may there is some miss configuration in your typoscript

Answer (score 1):

There is no `page.10.settings`:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html#

May you mean something like:

```
page = PAGE
page {
   10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
   10 {
      file = EXT:site_default/Resources/Private/Templates/MyTemplate.html
      settings {
         copyrightYear = 2013
      }
   }
}
```

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html?highlight=settings#settings

Then this should work

```
page = PAGE
page {
   10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
   10 {
      settings < plugin.tx_tester.settings
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks but this is the same from me :) page.10.settings < plugin.tx_tester.settings but it dont works :(

Comment: make sure your  custom extension typoscript  must be loaded before your PAGE object

Comment: yes, i load the page before!
if i use this: page.10.settings < plugin.tx_tester.settings it works, but i need this (no overright) page.10.settings =< plugin.tx_tester.settings

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can't use TypoScript references for settings, but only for cObjects.

From the TypoScript documentation:

> References are only resolved for **Content Objects**, otherwise references are not resolved. For example, you cannot use a reference `< plugin.tx_example.settings.foo` to find the value of `foo`. The value you get will be just `< plugin.tx_example.settings.foo` instead.

The provided example shows the copy operator `<`, but I'd consider this a typo in the docs.

---

Source: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptSyntaxReference/8.7/Syntax/TypoScriptSyntax/Index.html#references-the-sign